# I would like to turn off scrolling using css on a horizontal webpage through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i tried.

```
document.body.style.overflowX = hidden;
```

also tried

```
document.body.style.overflowY = hidden;
```

console  says error. That hidden is not defined.

Comment: If `hidden` is not defined, it needs to be. You probably mean to use a string, `'hidden'`.

Comment: ```document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; ``` or  ```document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; ``` should work. else you can target the body by giving it an id and target it as such:  ```document.getElementById("myidname").style.overflow = "hidden"; ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `hidden` should be enclosed in quotes.

So try `document.body.style.overflowX = 'hidden';` instead of `document.body.style.overflowX = hidden;`.